# Breaking Format and String provided into a list of string array

Tags: c#, string

I have a format( data Type - string ) say of the form {1}.{0}.{2}@xyz.com. Also, I have a string following the same format say bht.aay.ccch@xyz.com. How can I break the string into the format provided into a list or a string array or any other data structure ( Number provided in the format is the index where the corresponding strings should be stored). Delimiter can be anything like , or /

Example :-

```
1) Format - {0}.{1}@xyz.com  
   String - name0.name1@xyz.com  
   String array[]= { "name0", "name1"}
2) Format - {1}.{0}.{2}@xyz.com  
   String - pos0.pos1.pos2@xyz.com  
   String array[]= { "pos1", "pos0", "pos2"}
3) Format - {0}.{1}  
   String - name0.name1  
   String array[] = { "pos0", "pos1"}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? did you face any error? is `.`(period) is the only delimiter is used or it is different for different inputs?

Comment: It can be anything

Comment: You might be able to convert the format into a regular expression by replacing `{#}` with `(.*?)` and escaping other characters as needed.  However there's a problem that a format of `"{0}.{1}"` would match something like `"1.2.3"` in two different ways.

Comment: As an aside, I generally convert such code to use string interpolation when I come across it, e.g. `$"{foo} bar {baz}"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConAppCore
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test("{0}.{1}@xyz.com", "name0.name1@xyz.com");
            Test("{1}.{0}.{2}@xyz.com", "pos0.pos1.pos2@xyz.com");
            Test("{0}.{1}", "name0.name1");
        }
        static void Test(string format, string input)
        {
            string pattern = CreatePattern(format);
            var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

            var array = match.Groups
                .OfType<Group>()
                .Skip(1)
                .OrderBy(g => g.Name, StringComparer.Ordinal)
                .Select(g => g.Value)
                .ToArray();

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", array));
        }
        static string CreatePattern(string format)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var match = Regex.Match(format, @"(.*?)\{(\d+)\}");
            int index;
            int length;

            do
            {
                sb.Append(Regex.Escape(match.Groups[1].Value));
                sb.Append("(?'group").Append(match.Groups[2].Value).Append(@"'\w+)");

                index = match.Index;
                length = match.Length;

                match = match.NextMatch();

            } while (match.Success);

            sb.Append(Regex.Escape(format.Substring(index + length)));

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
           string[] inputs = { "name0.name1@xyz.com", "name0.name1@xyz.com", "name0.name1" };
            string pattern = "(?'path'.*)@(?'site'.*)";

            foreach(string input in inputs)
            {
                Match match = Regex.Match(input,pattern);
                string[] paths = match.Groups["path"].Value.Split(new char[] {'.'}).ToArray();
                string site = match.Groups["site"].Value;
                Console.WriteLine("Path : '{0}', Site : '{1}'", string.Join("-", paths), site);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```